# mayactl command for OpenEBS volume is showing errors

Tags: openebs

I am getting below erros while doing `mayactl volume list` comand from maya-apiserver pod

```
> Volume list error: template: OutputYamlTpl:24:74: executing
> "OutputYamlTpl" at <"running">: invalid value; expected string
```

I have preformed an upgrade from OpenEBS 0.7.2 to 0.8 recently.
I can give output of `kubectl get pvc -n openebs-redundant`

```
pvc-c1caeb0f-de77-11e8-b008-0050569db3cb   20Gi       RWO            Retain           Released   ci/db-testenv-ixsol-mysql                       openebs-redundant             62d
pvc-c7edb95e-cd3b-11e8-9384-fee6a1e98ebe   20Gi       RWO            Retain           Released   ci/eng-db-mysql                                 openebs-redundant             84d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been fixed with upcoming version 0.8.1 revision . This would work after a few attempts. First few attempt would due to initialization issue.
Github issue -- 870 (maya)